# Unpack the list element of DataFrame

Tags: python, list, pandas, unpack

I have this df:

```
l1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
l2 = ['x', ['y1', 'y2', 'y3'], 'z']
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(l1, l2)), columns = ['l1', 'l2'])
```

result:

```
  l1            l2
0  a             x
1  b  [y1, y2, y3]
2  c             z
```

What i need is to unpack the inner list in l2 and spread the corresponding value in l1 like this:

```
  l1  l2
0  a   x
1  b  y1
2  b  y2
3  b  y3
4  c   z
```

What is the proper way to do this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use [`numpy.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) for repeat values by legths by [`str.len`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.len.html) and flat values of nested `lists` by `chain`:

```
from  itertools import chain

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
        "l1": np.repeat(df.l1.values, df.l2.str.len()),
        "l2": list(chain.from_iterable(df.l2))})
print (df1)
  l1  l2
0  a   x
1  b  y1
2  b  y2
3  b  y3
4  c   z
```

**Timings**:

```
#[100000 rows x 2 columns]
np.random.seed(10)
N = 100000
l1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
l1 = np.random.choice(l1, N)
l2 = [list(tuple(string.ascii_letters[:np.random.randint(1, 10)])) for _ in np.arange(N)]
df = pd.DataFrame({"l1":l1, "l2":l2})
df.l2 = df.l2.apply(lambda x: x if len(x) !=1 else x[0])
#print (df)


In [91]: %timeit (pd.DataFrame([(left, right) for outer in zip(l1, l2) for left, right in zip_longest(*outer, fillvalue=outer[0])]))
1 loop, best of 3: 242 ms per loop

In [92]: %timeit (pd.DataFrame({ "l1": np.repeat(df.l1.values, df.l2.str.len()), "l2": list(chain.from_iterable(df.l2))}))
10 loops, best of 3: 84.6 ms per loop
```

**Conclusion**:

`numpy.repeat` is `3 times` faster as `zip_longest` solution in larger df.

EDIT:

For compare with loop version is necessery smaller df, because very slow:

```
#[1000 rows x 2 columns]
np.random.seed(10)
N = 1000
l1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
l1 = np.random.choice(l1, N)
l2 = [list(tuple(string.ascii_letters[:np.random.randint(1, 10)])) for _ in np.arange(N)]
df = pd.DataFrame({"l1":l1, "l2":l2})
df.l2 = df.l2.apply(lambda x: x if len(x) !=1 else x[0])
#print (df)
```

```
def alexey(df):
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns,index=df.index)[0:0]

    for idx in df.index:
        new_row = df.loc[idx, :].copy()
        for res in df.ix[idx, 'l2']:
            new_row.set_value('l2', res)
            df2.loc[len(df2)] = new_row
    return df2

print (alexey(df))

In [20]: %timeit (alexey(df))
1 loop, best of 3: 11.4 s per loop

In [21]: %timeit pd.DataFrame([(left, right) for outer in zip(l1, l2) for left, right in zip_longest(*outer, fillvalue=outer[0])])
100 loops, best of 3: 2.57 ms per loop

In [22]: %timeit pd.DataFrame({ "l1": np.repeat(df.l1.values, df.l2.str.len()), "l2": list(chain.from_iterable(df.l2))})
The slowest run took 4.42 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.41 ms per loop
```

Comment: can I get you to weigh in on my answer [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43020297/2336654) I answered late. I'm also on the road without my laptop and can't run any code 

Comment: Unfortunately I am on phone, so cannot test. But I get upvote.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a nested list comprehension with [itertools.zip_longest](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest).

```
import pandas as pd

from itertools import zip_longest

l1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
l2 = ['x', ['y1', 'y2', 'y3'], 'z']

expanded = [(left, right) for outer in zip(l1, l2) 
                          for left, right in zip_longest(*outer, fillvalue=outer[0])]

pd.DataFrame(expanded)
```

Result is...

```
   0   1
0  a   x
1  b  y1
2  b  y2
3  b  y3
4  c   z
```

To me this is on the border of being too long of a list comp. Also assumes that `l1` has no lists in it and will be doing the filling.

Answer (score 2):

For DataFrames with not constatnt number of columns i now do something like this:

```
l1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
l2 = ['x', ['y1', 'y2', 'y3'], 'z']
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(l1, l2)), columns = ['l1', 'l2'])
```

Since pandas 0.25.0 there is a built in [explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) method, which does exactly what this, preserving index:

```
df.explode('l2')
```

result:

```
  l1  l2
0  a   x
1  b  y1
1  b  y2
1  b  y3
2  c   z
```

If you need to refresh the index:

```
df.explode('l2').reset_index(drop=True)
```

result:

```
  l1  l2
0  a   x
1  b  y1
2  b  y2
3  b  y3
4  c   z
```

**OLD ANSWER:**

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns,index=df.index)[0:0]

for idx in df.index:
    new_row = df.loc[idx, :].copy()
    for res in df.ix[idx, 'l2']:
        new_row.set_value('l2', res)
        df2.loc[len(df2)] = new_row
```

It works, but this looks pretty much like bruteforce.

Comment: But I think it will be very slow, because loops :(

Comment: Fixed the code, can you please check timings? Yeah i guess its very slow too. Maybe loops can be optimized somehow (i am not an expert)

Answer (score 1):

Brute force, looping over the dataframe:

```
for idx in df.index:
    # This transforms the item in "l2" into an iterable list
    item = df.loc[idx, "l2"] if isinstance(df.loc[idx, "l2"], (list, tuple)) else [df.loc[idx, "l2"]]
    for element in item:
        print(df.loc[idx, "l1"], element)
```

returns

```
a x
b y1
b y2
b y3
c z
```