# Pandas sum of all word counts in column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas column that contains strings. I want to get a word count of all of the words in the entire column. What's the best way of doing that without looping through each value?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['some words', 'lots more words', 'hi']})
```

when run on `df['a']`, you should get 6

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use the [vectorized string operations](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html):

```
In [7]: df["a"].str.split().str.len().sum()
Out[7]: 6
```

which comes from

```
In [8]: df["a"].str.split()
Out[8]: 
0          [some, words]
1    [lots, more, words]
2                   [hi]
Name: a, dtype: object

In [9]: df["a"].str.split().str.len()
Out[9]: 
0    2
1    3
2    1
Name: a, dtype: int64

In [10]: df["a"].str.split().str.len().sum()
Out[10]: 6
```

Comment: On my way to doing this, v nice

Answer (score 5):

Another option using the `cat` string method. We will smash all strings together then split and count

```
len(df["a"].str.cat(sep=' ').split())
```

***elaborate test data***

```
li = [
    'Lorem', 'ipsum', 'dolor', 'sit', 'amet', 'consectetur',
    'adipiscing', 'elit', 'Integer', 'et', 'tincidunt', 'nisl',
    'Sed', 'pretium', 'arcu', 'nec', 'est', 'hendrerit',
    'vestibulum', 'Curabitur', 'a', 'nibh', 'justo', 'Praesent',
    'non', 'pellentesque', 'enim', 'ac', 'nulla', 'ut', 'mi',
    'diam', 'Aenean', 'placerat', 'ante', 'euismod', 'pulvinar',
    'augue', 'purus', 'ornare', 'erat', 'pharetra', 'mauris',
    'sapien', 'vitae', 'In', 'id', 'velit', 'quis', 'mattis',
    'condimentum', 'Cras', 'congue', 'neque', 'faucibus', 'nisi',
    'tempor', 'eget', 'Etiam', 'semper', 'Nulla', 'elementum',
    'magna', 'Donec', 'vel', 'ex', 'dictum', 'Aliquam', 'lobortis',
    'rutrum', 'ligula', 'Vivamus', 'eu', 'eros', 'Morbi', 'blandit',
    'rhoncus', 'consequat', 'orci', 'convallis', 'finibus', 'lorem',
    'urna', 'molestie', 'in', 'sed', 'luctus', 'Ut', 'imperdiet',
    'felis', 'Mauris', 'nunc', 'malesuada', 'lacinia', 'Vestibulum',
    'bibendum', 'risus', 'tortor', 'sollicitudin', 'aliquam',
    'primis', 'ultrices', 'posuere', 'cubilia', 'Curae',
    'Phasellus', 'turpis', 'auctor', 'venenatis', 'Pellentesque',
    'fermentum', 'accumsan', 'maximus', 'Fusce', 'ultricies',
    'tristique', 'sodales', 'suscipit', 'sagittis', 'at', 'cursus',
    'Nullam', 'dui', 'fringilla', 'mollis', 'Orci', 'varius',
    'natoque', 'penatibus', 'magnis', 'dis', 'parturient', 'montes',
    'nascetur', 'ridiculus', 'mus', 'facilisi', 'sem', 'viverra',
    'feugiat', 'aliquet', 'lectus', 'porta', 'Nunc', 'facilisis',
    'Duis', 'volutpat', 'scelerisque', 'Maecenas', 'tempus',
    'massa', 'laoreet', 'gravida', 'odio', 'iaculis', 'libero',
    'eleifend', 'leo', 'Quisque', 'ullamcorper', 'dignissim',
    'interdum', 'vulputate', 'lacus', 'vehicula', 'Nam', 'commodo',
    'dapibus', 'efficitur', 'tellus', 'Suspendisse', 'metus',
    'Proin', 'quam', 'porttitor', 'egestas'
]

df = pd.DataFrame(
    dict(a=[' '.join(
            np.random.choice(li, np.random.randint(5, 10, 1))
    ) for _ in range(10000)]))
```

***naive test results***

[image]

Comment: It's definitely the fastest of them all. I'll probably suggest a similar variant which marginally outperforms `str.cat` - `len(" ".join(df['a']).split())`

Comment: @NickilMaveli can you check my new concept please. I'll delete it if it's wrong

Comment: You don't have to. lgtm

Answer (score 3):

```
df.a.str.extractall('(\w+)').count()[0]
```

This extracts all words (matches the regex `(\w+)`) in a each cell in `a` and puts them in a new frame that looks something like:

```
             0
  match       
0 0       some
  1      words
1 0       lots
  1       more
  2      words
2 0         hi
```

You can then just do a `count` on the rows to get the number of words.

Note that you can always change the regex if you want. For example, if some words might contain punctuation characters you can define a words as any series of non-whitespace characters and do something like:

```
df.a.str.extractall('(\S+)').count()[0]
```

instead

**EDIT**

If you care about speed at all, use DSM's solution instead:

Basic time test using ipython's `%timeit`:

```
%timeit df.a.str.extractall('(\S+)').count()[0] 
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.28 ms per loop

%timeit df["a"].str.split().str.len().sum()
1000 loops, best of 3: 447 µs per loop
```

Comment: Can you time my answer as well?  Thx

Comment: @piRSquared I got about 100 µs for yours.  speedy!

Answer (score 1):

Numbers of words could be gotten by str count blanks+1, then sum()

```
(df.a.str.count(' ')+1).sum()
```